Unable to load Bidirectional LSTM model from .keras file
This is my first time working with tensorflow and keras and am having a problem saving and load models. I have figured out it specifically has to do with the Bidirectional LSTM layer but do not know what to do from there.
Here is my code:
model = Sequential()

model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128, activation='tanh'))) ### problem line
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))


optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5, restore_best_weights=True)
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=3, verbose=1)

model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=3, validation_data=(X_test_scaled, y_test), callbacks=[early_stopping, reduce_lr])
model.summary()

model.save('models/sample_model.keras')
model = load_model('models/sample_model.keras')

Loading the model produces this error:
ValueError: A total of 1 objects could not be loaded. Example error message for object <LSTMCell name=lstm_cell, built=True>:

Layer 'lstm_cell' expected 3 variables, but received 0 variables during loading. Expected: ['kernel', 'recurrent_kernel', 'bias']

List of objects that could not be loaded:
[<LSTMCell name=lstm_cell, built=True>]

I have tried adding input_shape into the bidirectional parameters but the same error occurs. I also tried saving as .h5 file rather than .keras with no luck. I looked at the keras documentation and I thought I was doing it just as they suggested but I must have messed up somewhere.
I even commented one line at a time, saved, and loaded the models. The only time the error occurs is when I include the Bidirectional with an LSTM layer. Having an LSTM layer by itself did not cause an error.
Any ideas why this is happening?
EDIT: I am using tensorflow 2.16.1 and keras 3.2.0

you dont give a useable minimal reproducible example, you dont provide any example input or output, we can't help because you haven't given us enough information.

The only solution that worked for me was to revert to tensorflow 2.15.1 and keras 2.15.0 and it now works as intended

This seems to be a problem with the 2.16.1 version of tensorflow. You can load the model, but not the weights when upgrading to the nightly version.
The .keras format is kinda like a zip file and it holds the model architecture in the config.json file. Trying to build the model from that json file using tf.keras.models.model_from_json() results in this error as well, so I suspect there's a problem with how the json is being handled in this version.
Even in the nightly version, I get this error when doing model.load_weights('model.weights.h5')
